# How to use the use WooCommerce functions in a WordPress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

How would I use WooCommerce hooks in my plugin? Here is what I am trying to do:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_edit_product_columns', 'pA_manage_posts_columns');
function pA_manage_posts_columns($columns, $post_type = 'product') {
global $woocommerce;
if ( in_array( $post_type, array( 'product') ) ) {
    $columns['offering_price'] = __( 'offering price', 'your_text_domain' ); // this offering price title 
    $columns['offering_qty'] = __( 'Qty', 'your_text_domain' ); // add the quantity title
    }
unset($columns['name']);
return $columns;
```

Here is how I include WooCommerce in my plugin:

```
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$base_dir = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)  . $ds . '..') . $ds;
$file = "{$base_dir}woocommerce{$ds}woocommerce.php"; 
include_once($file);
```

Still can't get the output from

```
print_r($woocommerce);
```

Comment: you should not include the plugin, but activate it ...

Comment: Thank you, here is how i activated the plugin:'code' include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
activate_plugin(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php'); still can't get the hook adding the new columns or unset columns.

Comment: Why don´t you just activate the plugin normally `?? why do you need to include it ?

Comment: if you mean from the admin panel, it is already activated, but i can't get the woocommerce filters working.

Comment: I can however get the result from the print_r($woocommerce);

Comment: I think the function you referenced  wrote does not exists as a filter and if it is , it needs to return `$existing_columns` . I would assume you need `manage_edit-product_columns` as a filter. look here http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_edit_product_columns.html#69-105 and maybe this will help   http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-thumbnail-to-the-column-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixed the hook with the callback. The original call is in [this file](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocommerce/trunk/admin/post-types/product.php#L107):

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'woocommerce_edit_product_columns' );
```

Your code should be:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'pA_manage_posts_columns', 15 );

function pA_manage_posts_columns( $columns ) 
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $columns['offering_price'] = __( 'offering price', 'your_text_domain' ); // this offering price title 
    $columns['offering_qty'] = __( 'Qty', 'your_text_domain' ); // add the quantity title
    unset($columns['name']);
    return $columns;
}
```

Note that there's no `post_type` parameter in the callback. The filter hook is already telling what the post type is: `manage_edit-product_columns`.

As Obmerk Kronen has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110047/how-do-i-use-the-use-the-woocommerce-functions-in-a-wordpress-plugin#comment28259943_19110047), there's no need to include any WooCommerce file, all its functionality is available to you already.

Comment: Thank you, it works now for adding new columns, however i can't get it to unset the the columns.

Comment: @user2833755, we need to put a lower priority (`15`, default is `10`), so our filter executes *after* WC has added its columns. Answer updated and working now.